# Como exportar una base de datos en js?

Tags: javascript

tengo una base de datos en un archivo llamado basededatos.js que necesito trabajar desde otros dos archivos con nombre main.js y datos.js quisiera exportarla para poder trabajar mis funciones datos.js y en el archivo main.js trabajar la interaccion con el DOM. Como podria hacerlo?

Esta es mi base de datos, esta en el archivo basededatos.js

```
export default {
  "games": "Olympic Games",
  "year": 2016,
  "season": "summer",
  "city": "Rio de Janeiro",
  "athletes": [
    {
      "name": "Giovanni Abagnale",
      "gender": "M",
      "height": "198",
      "weight": "90",
      "sport": "Rowing",
      "team": "Italy",
      "noc": "ITA",
      "age": 21,
      "event": "Rowing Men's Coxless Pairs",
      "medal": "Bronze"
    },
    {
      "name": "Patimat Abakarova",
      "gender": "F",
      "height": "165",
      "weight": "49",
      "sport": "Taekwondo",
      "team": "Azerbaijan",
      "noc": "AZE",
      "age": 21,
      "event": "Taekwondo Women's Flyweight",
      "medal": "Bronze"
  }
  ]
}
```

Aquí tengo esto en otros dos archivos:

en el main.js

```
    importar  {  ejemplo  }  desde  './data.js' ;
    // importar datos de './data/lol/lol.js';
    importar  datos  de  './data/pokemon/pokemon.js' ;
    // importar datos de './data/rickandmorty/rickandmorty.js';
    
    consola . log ( ejemplo ,  datos ) ;
```

y en datos.js tengo esto:

```
// estas funciones son de ejemplo

 ejemplo de exportación const  = ( ) => {    
  return  'ejemplo' ;
} ;

exportar  const  otroEjemplo  =  ( )  =>  {
  devuelve  'OMG' ;
} ;
```

Comment: Exportarla de dónde a dónde? Qué has intentado para resolver tu pregunta y qué fallos tienes en esos intentos? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade toda esta información

Comment: hola, tienes algo avanzado? algún código creado?, yo por lo menos leyendo tu duda no logro entender bien qué es lo que necesitas. saludos

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, agradeceria si me pueden ayudar. Necesito obtener los datos para comenzar a realizar mis funciones pero no he logrado exportar ni importar nada.

Comment: Si revisas la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#syntax) sobre default exports y cómo importarlos, lo entenderás. El primer ejemplo te muestra cómo hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Este código que muestras lo ejecutas en un navegador o en NodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que todos los archivos estan dentro de la misma carpeta.

Primero agrega un nombre a tu exportacion:

```
export const database =  {
  "games": "Olympic Games",
  "year": 2016,
  "season": "summer",
  "city": "Rio de Janeiro",
  "athletes": [
    {
      "name": "Giovanni Abagnale",
      "gender": "M",
      "height": "198",
      "weight": "90",
      "sport": "Rowing",
      "team": "Italy",
      "noc": "ITA",
      "age": 21,
      "event": "Rowing Men's Coxless Pairs",
      "medal": "Bronze"
    },
    {
      "name": "Patimat Abakarova",
      "gender": "F",
      "height": "165",
      "weight": "49",
      "sport": "Taekwondo",
      "team": "Azerbaijan",
      "noc": "AZE",
      "age": 21,
      "event": "Taekwondo Women's Flyweight",
      "medal": "Bronze"
  }
  ]
}
```

Ahora importa tu base de datos:

```
import { database } from './database'

// ahora usa tu base de datos

console.log(database.year)
// output 2016
```

Dentro de este mundo del software a una base de datos dentro de una variable le solemos decir "mockup" ya que en realidad no es una base de datos, si no una maqueta de la base de datos, tal vez por eso tantos usuarios se confudieron.

Comment: Ayudaría que explicases al OP, por qué la diferencia de usar `export default` o `export const` ya que ambas opciones son válidas.

Comment: Gracias por responder, en mi caso los archivos no estan dentro de la misma carpeta por eso necesito exportar e importar!